# Get number of occurrences of certain attribute in a related table in an aggregation in django

Tags: python, sql, django

I'm creating an extensible analytics app for django, the idea is to have a table with the events you wish to track and a table that connects events, to a certain date and a certain user.

Here is my main model:

```
class Events_Tracked(models.Model):
    data_point = models.ForeignKey('Data_Points', related_name='data_point')
    event_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    user = models.ForeignKey('Users', related_name= 'user_tracked')
```

My problem now is to create a django query that can group the events tracked by month, and return the number of tracked events (rows) where data_point__id is the id I specify.

Preety sure I could do:

```
Events_Tracked.objects.values('event_date__month').annotate(Count('data_point')).filter(data_point__id=1)
```

But that would be limited to the count of a single data point, I need a query that can return a count row for each of the data points I want to track.

EDIT: Another very important query I need to build is for each month, get the number of users who had events tracked, whose data_point id is in a list of id's.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. Could you tell us what is your desired output exactly ? Do you mean you want to pass a list of data_points to your query and get back a list of tuples corresponding to (month, number_of_data_points) ?

Comment: I want to pass a list of data_point id's (ex: 1, 2, 3) and get the number of ocurrences of each of those data point for each month.